# set min/max Monotouch.Dialog.TimeElement

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is it possible with the time element to force a min and max value?
e.g. can only scroll back 5 mins and forward 10?

I am wanting to set these values but can't find any help with the documentation and the api.

Thank you

Comment: MonoTouch.Dialog is open source and really easy to customize, either by inheritance or by rolling your own `Element`. You can browse its source code from https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit TimeElement class and override CreatePicker function
something like

```
class MyClass : TimeElement
{
    public MyClass(string caption, DateTime date) : base(caption, date)
    {
    }

    public override UIDatePicker CreatePicker()
    {
        var uiDatePicker = base.CreatePicker();
        uiDatePicker.MaximumDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        uiDatePicker.MinimumDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
        return uiDatePicker;
    }
}
```